# How to implement NSTableViewRowlView like Xcode IB object selector

Tags: nstablerowview

I am trying to implement a `NSTableView` that looks similar to the Xcode IB object selector (bottom right panel).  As shown below when a row is selected a full width horizontal line is draw above and below the selected row.

I have successfully created a subclass of `NSTableRowView` and have used the isNextRowSelected property to determine whether to draw a full width separator and this almost works.

The issue is the row above the selected row is not being redrawn unless you happened to select a row and then select the row below it immediately afterwards.

How can I efficiently get the NSTableView to redraw the row above the selected row every time ?

[image]

Here is my implementation when a single row is selected
[image]

And another if a the row immediately below is now selected - which is what I want.
[image]

```
/// This subclass draws a partial line as the separator for unselected rows and a full width line above and below for selected rows
/// |    ROW     |
/// | ---------- |  unselected separator

/// |------------|  selected separator on row above selected row
/// |    ROW     |
/// |------------|  selected separator
///
/// Issue: Row above selected row does not get redrawn when selected row is deselected
class OSTableRowView: NSTableRowView {

    let separatorColor  = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.35, alpha: 1)
    let selectedSeparatorColor  = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.15, alpha: 1)
    let selectedFillColor       = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.82, alpha: 1)


    override func drawSeparator(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let yBottom = self.bounds.height
        let gap: CGFloat = 4.0
        let xLeft: CGFloat = 0.0
        let xRight = xLeft + self.bounds.width

        let lines = NSBezierPath()

        /// Draw a full width separator if the item is selected or if the next row is selected
        if self.isSelected || self.isNextRowSelected {
            selectedSeparatorColor.setStroke()
            lines.move(to: NSPoint(x: xLeft, y: yBottom))
            lines.line(to: NSPoint(x: xRight, y: yBottom))
            lines.lineWidth = 1.0
        } else {
            separatorColor.setStroke()
            lines.move(to: NSPoint(x: xLeft+gap, y: yBottom))
            lines.line(to: NSPoint(x: xRight-gap, y: yBottom))
            lines.lineWidth = 0.0
        }

        lines.stroke()
    }

    override func drawSelection(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        if self.selectionHighlightStyle != .none {
            let selectionRect = self.bounds
            selectedSeparatorColor.setStroke()
            selectedFillColor.setFill()
            selectionRect.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

After reading a few other posts I tried adding code to cause the preceding row to be redraw.  This appears to have not effect.

```
func selectionShouldChange(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Bool {
        let selection = tableView.selectedRow
        if selection > 0 {
            tableView.setNeedsDisplay(tableView.rect(ofRow: selection-1))
            tableView.displayIfNeeded()
        }
        return true
    }
```

And nor does this.

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let tableView = self.sidebarOutlineView else {
            return
        }
        let row = tableView.selectedRow
            if row > 0 {
                tableView.setNeedsDisplay(tableView.rect(ofRow: row-1))
                print("row-1 update rect: \(tableView.rect(ofRow: row-1))")
            }

    }
```

Seems odd that neither of these trigger redrawing of the row - am I missing something here!

EDIT:
OK I found something that seems to work OKish - there is still a visible lag in the redrawing of the row above the deselected row which is not present in the XCode tableView.

```
var lastSelectedRow = -1 {
        didSet {
            guard let tableView = self.sidebarOutlineView else {
                return
            }
            if oldValue != lastSelectedRow {

                if oldValue > 0 {
                    if let view = tableView.rowView(atRow: oldValue-1, makeIfNecessary: false) {
                        view.needsDisplay = true
                    }
                }
                if lastSelectedRow > 0 {
                    if let view = tableView.rowView(atRow: lastSelectedRow-1, makeIfNecessary: false) {
                        view.needsDisplay = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and then simply set the value of the variable `lastSelectedRow = tableView.selectedRow` in the `tableViewSelectionDidChange(:)` method.

I think perhaps the tableView needs to be subclassed to make sure that both rows are redrawn in the same update cycle.

Answer (score 0):

This NSTableRowView subclass seems to work fine with no visible lag in redrawing the row above any more.

The solution was to override the `isSelected` properly and set `needsDisplay` on the row above each time.

```
/// This subclass draws a partial line as the separator for unselected rows and a full width line above and below for selected rows
/// |    ROW     |
/// | ---------- |  unselected separator

/// |------------|  selected separator on row above selected row
/// |    ROW     |
/// |------------|  selected separator
///
/// Issue: Row above selected row does not get redrawn when selected row is deselected
class OSTableRowView: NSTableRowView {

    let separatorColor  = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.35, alpha: 1)
    let selectedSeparatorColor  = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.15, alpha: 1)
    let selectedFillColor       = NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.82, alpha: 1)

    /// Override this and whenever it is changed set the previous row to be updated
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if let tableView = self.superview as? NSTableView {
                let row = tableView.row(for: self)
                if row > 0 {
                    tableView.rowView(atRow: row-1, makeIfNecessary: false)?.needsDisplay = true
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }

    override func drawSeparator(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let yBottom = self.bounds.height
        let gap: CGFloat = 4.0
        let xLeft: CGFloat = 0.0
        let xRight = xLeft + self.bounds.width

        let lines = NSBezierPath()

        /// Draw a full width separator if the item is selected or if the next row is selected
        if self.isSelected || self.isNextRowSelected {
            selectedSeparatorColor.setStroke()
            lines.move(to: NSPoint(x: xLeft, y: yBottom))
            lines.line(to: NSPoint(x: xRight, y: yBottom))
            lines.lineWidth = 1.0
        } else {
            separatorColor.setStroke()
            lines.move(to: NSPoint(x: xLeft+gap, y: yBottom))
            lines.line(to: NSPoint(x: xRight-gap, y: yBottom))
            lines.lineWidth = 0.0
        }

        lines.stroke()
    }

    override func drawSelection(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        if self.selectionHighlightStyle != .none {
            let selectionRect = self.bounds
            selectedSeparatorColor.setStroke()
            selectedFillColor.setFill()
            selectionRect.fill()
        }
    }
}
```